# removeClass() if it exists

Tags: jquery, html

This function adds a `rotated` class to my button when I click it. The button has an arrow on it which points in the direction the panel has slid.

How could I remove the rotated class when I click the button again?

```
$("#btnDiv").click(function (){
     $('#slidePanel').toggle( "slide",{direction: 'right'});
     $('#btnDiv').addClass('rotated');
});
```

Something like this maybe?

```
if('rotated'){
    removeClass('rotated')
}else{
    addClass('rotated')
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `.toggleClass()`

```
$('#btnDiv').toggleClass('rotated');
```

That adds it if it's missing, and removes it if it's present. There's also `.is()` to check for things like that:

```
if ($('#btnDiv').is('.rotated'))
```

or more simply:

```
if ($('#btnDiv').hasClass('rotated'))
```

Comment: ...and if you ever need to check if a class is set: `hasClass()` : http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Excellent! What a quick fix! Cheers Pointy!

Comment: @Virus721 there's no need to check if all you want to do is add the class; `.addClass()` won't add it twice.

Comment: Okay, so this question has no reason to be then.

Comment: @Virus721 I'm pretty sure that the OP wants to remove the class if it's present, and add the class if it's missing.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion Virus, but Pointy's worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped with this:
$(this).toggleClass('selectedTrack_row').siblings().removeClass('xyzClass');

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
if($('#btnDiv').hasClass('rotated')){
   $('#btnDiv').removeClass('rotated')
}else{
  $('#btnDiv').addClass('rotated')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.toggleClass()` to acheive that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#btnDiv").click(function (){
    $('#slidePanel').toggle( "slide",{direction: 'right'});
    if($('#btnDiv').hasClass('rotated')){
          $('#btnDiv').removeClass('rotated');
    }
    else{
         $('#btnDiv').addClass('rotated');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#btnDiv').hasClass('rotated')){
   $('#btnDiv').removeClass('rotated')
}else{
   $('#btnDiv').addClass('rotated')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you simple swith the class on click

```
$('.myclassname').on('click', function(){
    $('.myclass h2').toggleClass( 'first_class', 'second_class');
});
```